# JSON Response from Remote server

Tags: java, json, servlets, gson

I am trying to create an application to return response from the server in json format by invoking **getSessionKey** method. The response should be these three parameters.**message**,**status** and **sessionKey** in this format

```
 {
    "message": "Successful",
    "status": 0,
    "sessionKey": "f85d1246c98f11e"
   }
```

Here is the java code.

```
 private static String sessionKeyResponse(){
     try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient =HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {

       String url="http://myurl.com:8080/getSessionKey";
       String body="";
       HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
       StringEntity params = new StringEntity(body);

       request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
       request.setEntity(params);
       HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
       String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(),"UTF 8");
       com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
       Response respuesta = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);

       System.out.println(respuesta.getMessage());
       System.out.println(respuesta.getStatus());
       System.out.println(respuesta.getSessionKey());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
   return "";
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "message","status","sessionKey" })
    public class Response{

        private String message;
        private String status;
        private String sessionKey;

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        @JsonProperty("message")
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        @JsonProperty("status")
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getSessionKey() {
            return sessionKey;
        }

    }
```

This is the response I am getting from the server when i run the app **Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 1.**

Any response will be appriciated.

Comment: please check your result of `json` and provide the stack trace if possible

Comment: print this result: String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(),"UTF-8");

Comment: @Wilson I have printed out the json but still I dont get the right response

Comment: @Tiina this is the tracktrace    `{
  "message" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input",
  "status" : 9003
} `

Comment: Based on your description, you are making a server? But the sessionKeyResponse method is a client. Using this method as a client, and I implemented a server that returns the same bean, I didn't meet such an error : unexpected token end of file....